# Retrieve Integer value from string in a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a gridview, when inserting data into the table `dept(100, 1, 'IT')` and when fetch the data from two tables `emp` and `dept` the records look like below grid:

```
EMpNo    DeptNo  DeptName
Harshal   1        IT
```

My problem is that, when I click on a grid view all records shows in respected text boxes
but issue is, I got all data except `empno`. Here I get as Name of employee instead of name  I want to `Empno`.

Comment: Show your binding code ?

Comment: And the query you are using to get these data from database please.

Comment: show how are you binding empno?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
  select empno,deptno,deptname from emp inner join dept on emp.dept.id=dept.id
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal yes. you are correct, then please check the bindings and also the datatypes you have specified